# Why does my quiz does not start on touchscreen?

Tags: javascript, touchscreen, touchstart

So, I wrote a quiz on JavaScript. It works perfectly on computes, but on touchscreen it does not start.

I changed
`start.addEventListener('click', startQuiz);`

to

`start.addEventListener('touchstart', startQuiz);`

But is still does not start. Should I add something else?

`start.addEventListener('touchstart', startQuiz);`

```
start.addEventListener('touchstart', startQuiz);    
function startQuiz(){
        start.style.display = "none";
        startText.style.display = "none";
        renderQuestion();
        quiz.style.display = "block";
        renderProgress();
        renderCounter();
        TIMER = setInterval(renderCounter,1000); // 1000ms = 1s
    }
```

Comment: Probably it works fine with with 'click' event but I'd guess you have an unhandled exception. I'd suggest to find a way to read console log of the phone. There are ways to do it

Comment: You can also use `pointerdown` to handle both mouse and touch at the same time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events

Comment: Connect your phone to your computer, open Chrome on both. In the computer's Chrome, open the dev tools, and from the menu, select "More tools" -> "Remote devices". From there you can see the phone screen and mobile Chrome's dev tools.

Comment: As it is working for some other people (answer below), but still frozen on line, looks like it might be the touchscreen computers problem. Maybe update will do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
start.addEventListener('click touch', startQuiz);
```

This will bind both click and touch.

Comment: This does not work in base javascript. The JQuery library supports this syntax, but `.addEventListener()` does not.

Comment: Oh i see, Thanks @Shilly

Answer (score 0):

I tried your coding it is working fine

```js
let start =document.getElementById("start");
let quiz =document.getElementById("quiz");


start.addEventListener('touchstart', startQuiz);    
function startQuiz(){
alert('Working')
        start.style.display = "none";
        startText.style.display = "none";
        renderQuestion();
        quiz.style.display = "block";
        renderProgress();
        renderCounter();
        TIMER = setInterval(renderCounter,1000); 
        }
```

```html
<div id='start'>start</div>


<div id='quiz'>34343</div>
```

Comment: What is `false` here, you should explain this.

Comment: [See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) "A Boolean indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree"

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the code was correct. The chrome browser that I was using was extremely outdated. On latest version quiz works perfectly! :)